# How to run code on React.useReducer bailout

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to write a library that processes dispatched useReducer actions. However, they need to be processed only once I have the new react state.

The idea in the following example is to buffer all the actions as they happen and then after the component rerenders get the new state and send all the buffered actions with the new state into the processor (simple logger function in this case). Problem is, that won't work if the component bails out of rendering, because the component won't rerender and so the useEffect callback won't get called either.

```
function logger(action, state) {
    // this should log every action immediately once its processed by react
    // state must be up-to-date (after all batched state changes are processed)
    console.log({action, state});
}
const buffer = [];

const Component = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
        (state, action) => {
            // bail out if there is no change
            if (action.value === state.someState) return state;
            return {someState: action.value};
        },
        {someState: 1}
    );
    const loggedDispatch = (action) => {
        dispatch(action);
        // Can't run the logger here as I don't have the new state yet
        // so I am buffering the actions instead for later
        buffer.push(action);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        // Now I have the new state, so I can run the logger
        // Problem is that this won't run if the reducer bailed out of render
        while (buffer.length) {
            logger(buffer.shift(), state);
        }
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={() => loggedDispatch({value: 1})}>Set to 1</div>
            <div onClick={() => loggedDispatch({value: 2})}>Set to 2</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Any idea how to fix this with react hooks?

With class components it was possible to use

```
this.setState(state => state, function () {
    console.log('This runs regardless of bailout');
})
```

But react hooks such as useState or useReducer don't support the second parameter.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-pine-lebrb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Couldn't you mimic this using a custom reducer function that first calls your regular useReducer dispatch, and depending on the outcome from that you call your logger? There's an example of using a middleware in useReducer at https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usereducer-middleware - is this something that would work for you?

Comment: @Patrick thx for sharing the link, I went through it but unfortunately the author of the article has the same issues in his code as I do - namely a) for the normal middleware he has only the old state or the transient state from that single reducer b) his afterware implementation is also not going to get called if the component bails out of rendering :(

Comment: I don't know if you've seen it, but there's [several ideas for workarounds here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15344)

Comment: @Nikki9696 hm, looks like all the current workarounds rely on sideeffects in reducer which isn't very safe because of React concurrency and other optimizations. At least It's nice to see I am not the only one trying to figure this out and that there probably isn't good answer right now.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is related to initial value that in `{someState: 1}` equal to value of first div button because when I click the second div button everything is going to be good.
this when I click first button

[image]

and this when click the second

[image]

> Bailing out of a dispatch
> If you return the same value from a Reducer Hook as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)

this is the quote of react [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) about return same value witch maybe your problem.
I hope this useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom hook that will use `useReducer` internally. In addition to the default functionality of `useReducer` it'll pass the previous state, next state and the action dispatched to your middleware.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/use-reducer-with-middleware-y2hvb?file=/src/index.js

```js
const {
  useCallback,
  useReducer
} = React;
const {
  render
} = ReactDOM

const useReducerWithMiddleware = (reducer, initialState, ...middlewares) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((prevState, action) => {
    const nextState = reducer(prevState, action);

    middlewares.forEach((middleware) =>
      middleware(prevState, nextState, action)
    );

    return nextState;
  }, initialState);

  return [state, dispatch];
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === CHANGE_TEXT_ACTION_TYPE) {
    return { ...state,
      text: action.payload
    };
  }
  return state;
};

const initialState = {
  text: "foo"
};

const loggerMiddleware = (prevState, nextState, action) => {
  console.log(`${action.type} is fired with payload = ${action.payload}.`);
  console.log(`prev state is equal to \n${JSON.stringify(prevState, null, 2)}`);
  console.log(`next state is equal to \n${JSON.stringify(nextState, null, 2)}`);
};

const CHANGE_TEXT_ACTION_TYPE = "changeText";

const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducerWithMiddleware(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    loggerMiddleware
  );

  const handleButtonClick = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: CHANGE_TEXT_ACTION_TYPE,
      payload: state.text === "foo" ? "bar" : "foo"
    });
  }, [dispatch, state]);

  return <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>{state.text}</button>;
};

render(<App /> , document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This unfortunately won't work well. Reducers can be called with the same action multiple times (e.g. in strict mode or due to inline reducer or some optimizations). In concurrent mode the whole thing could be run and thrown away before the commit phase. Also, it would run the middleware with transient states rather than the final state after all actions in batch are handled - this could be solved with some buffering and running everything after last action, but it still suffers from similar problems as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom hook and use that,

I have created a sample, check this out this might help

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dispatcher

I have given suggestion in GitHub issue as well

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15344#issuecomment-868204394

```
import { useReducer, useEffect } from "react";

let cb = () => {};
function useDispatch() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (state, action) => {
      if (action.value === state.someState) return state;
      return { someState: action.value };
    },
    { someState: 0 }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    cb(state);
  }, [state]);

  return [
    state,
    (action, callback) => {
      cb = callback;
      dispatch(action);
    },
  ];
}

const Component = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useDispatch();
  const loggedDispatch = (action) => {
    console.log("pre-state", state);
    dispatch(action, (newState) => {
      console.log("new-state", newState);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => loggedDispatch({ value: 1 })}>Set to 1</div>
      <div onClick={() => loggedDispatch({ value: 2 })}>Set to 2</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The new state value is not logged on bailout (when you set the state to the same value).

Comment: It won't be logged, because the state has not changed. In useReducer you can change to get everytime

Comment: That was my question though, how to actually log it even if the state won't change - logging it just when it changes works in my example too. I can't put the log into reducer because a) it is a side effect and the reducer can be called multiple times due to various optimizations b) I don't want transient state, I want the final state after everything in current batch is processed (same as you would get it in render of the component).

Comment: @MartinKadlec I have updated the live example, Check now.

Comment: Now it logs it, but it prevents the bailout so the component rerenders even if there is no state change.